# iOS: Handle Orientation change without enabling landscape mode on View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation

My Swift app's View Controller is fixed to portrait mode at all times, but the View Controller has an embedded AV video player (added as a child view controller) which should switch to fullscreen mode on device orientation change to landscape.

Problem I am facing is, if I don't enable landscape mode on the View Controller, I am unable to detect orientation changes (tried with `NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientation`, `NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange`) & hence unable to trigger player fullscreen.

I want my View Controller to ***not*** react to orientation changes, as it causes my auto layout views to stretch and adapt to screen size change, but at the same time I want the orientation change to reach the Child View Controller ie., the video player so it can handle switch between fullscreen mode/inline mode.

```
if let playerVC = createPlayerViewController() as? (UIViewController & MyEmbedPlayer) {

    // Set up events delegate.
    self.playerViewController = playerVC
    self.playerViewController?.setEventsDelegate(self)

    // PlayerViewController added as child of View Controller
    self.addChildViewController(self.playerViewController!)
}

let managedPlayerView = self.playerViewController?.view
managedPlayerView?.removeFromSuperview()
managedPlayerView?.frame = self.playerView.bounds
managedPlayerView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

playerView.addSubview(managedPlayerView!)

self.playerViewController?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
self.playerViewController?.setVideoURL(streamURL)
```

***TL;DR: I do not want my screen elements to react to orientation change, but still want my child view controller to receive orientation change events.***

Comment: do you need  just  `AVPlayerViewController` support  landscape

Comment: @a.masri yes, I am trying to get the player view controller to support landscape, and retain its parent view controller in portrait. But I see that when player enters landscape fullscreen and returns back to parent view controller, the parent view controller is rendered in landscape as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
class MYAVPlayerViewController:AVPlayerViewController{

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
        return .all // or you can replace this landscape
    }
}
```

call in your controller

```
 let myAVPlayerViewController = MYAVPlayerViewController()
        myAVPlayerViewController.player = player
        self.present(myAVPlayerViewController, animated: true) { 
            self.player.play()

        }
```

> Note : Please make sure the check just portrait in General -> device
>   orientation